# Как получить размер и вес картинки на js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть ссылка на картинку, можно ли получить ширину высоту и размер картинки на js?

Пример кода на: [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/085a9z21/3/)

```
<a href="./img/1.jpg" >Картинка 1</a>
  <br>
<a href="./img/2.jpg" >Картинка 2</a>
  <br>
<a href="./img/3.jpg" >Картинка 3</a>
   <br><br>
<div id="image_url"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('a').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
 var img_url = $(this).attr('href');
 $("#image_url").text(img_url);     
});
```

Comment: `.width(200);` -- это установить, а получить `var w = .... .width();`

Comment: @Stack Извините я вас не совсем понял. Мне нужно получить, реальную высоту и ширину картинки  на `js`.

Comment: лучше всего при генерации страницы их выяснять, вставлять как атрибут ссылки, а потом просто отображать при нажатии

Answer (score 1):

Получить размер картинки можно. Если нет возможности добавить атрибуты к ссылкам на сервере, можно сделать это на клиенте. Придется сделать ajax запрос до сервера, браузер подгрузит картинку, и размеры будут получены асинхронно:

```
$('a').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var img_url = $(this).attr('href');
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = img_url; //здесь начнется загрузка картинки
    img.onload = function(){
        console.log('LOAD', img.width, img.height); // а вот здесь мы уже знаем ее размеры
    };       
 });
```

Проверку на ошибку загрузки не добавлял.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего при генерации страницы их выяснять, вставлять как атрибут ссылки, а потом просто отображать при нажатии.

Примерно так:

```js
$('[data-href]').on('click', function() {
  $('#prev').attr('src', $(this).data('href'));
  var str = 'Пропорции: ' + $(this).data('dims') + '<br>Размер: ' + $(this).data('size');
  $('#descr').html(str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-href="http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png" data-dims="200x300" data-size="500KB">Картинка 1</a>
<br>
<a data-href="http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png" data-dims="300x400" data-size="1MB">Картинка 2</a>
<br>
<a data-href="http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png" data-dims="400x500" data-size="123KB">Картинка 3</a>
<br>
<br>
<img id="prev" src="./img/none.jpg" alt="image" />
<div id="descr"></div>
```

Comment: Ответ хороший, только я не могу изменить ссылки на картинки, потому что они генерируются скриптом на `php`.

Comment: Но все равно что-то менять придётся. Может быть тогда ajax запрос делать, который вернёт все необходимое?

Comment: Так об `Ajax` я тоже думал, на `php` это было бы гораздо проще, но за какой-то картинки постоянно отправлять запросы.

Comment: Ну и что? Если Ващ запрос только проверяет картинки, т.е. только с файлами работает, то Ваш сервер этого даже не заметит

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Половину дела уже решил, осталось получить ширину высоту и размер картинки.